# Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension - Aptana

Tags: ruby-on-rails, build, rubygems, aptana, devkit

I am getting this error while doing bundle install.
I checked that my RailsInstaller directory does not contain any spaces. 
Also the Devkit path I added in the path variable.
I am not sure why am I getting this error.

Here is the error:

```
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe: invalid switch in RUBYOPT: -S (RuntimeError)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same issue, this hasn't worked for me so far, but maybe it will help you:

Run the command `gem install json --platform=ruby`.  That appears to install the gem, but it doesn't seem to affect bundler in any way.

**Update:**

I found out that `bundle` was installing into the vendor/bundle folder in the app itself, so I deleted the bundle file inside vendor.  I also tried running `bundle clean`.  After that I tried running `bundle install --system` (Note: I also deleted Gemfile.lock).  That seemed to get rid of this error, but now I have a diffrent one with the eventmachine gem.